# Как в новом Xcode 6 создать приложение под ios 6.1.3?

Tags: xcode

Как в новом Xcode 6 создать приложение под ios 6.1.3? Можно как-то добавить в Xcode такую возможность?

Answer (score 1):

Как и в предыдущих. Выставить Deployment Target в настройках проекта или таргета.

Comment: Спасибо, нашол